# How to start autoplay owl-carousel in both direction when hover over owl-nav button

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

I am trying to active autoplay state on hover over nav-button but it's working only for one direction either Right to left or left to right.
I have done some success in this process but I am not able to fixed this problem.

I have implemented on a single button some next button but it's not working on Prev working continuously it gets stop after one movement.

For code reference, I have attached code codepen link.

`enter code here`https://codepen.io/Dushyant9211/pen/LYPygaj?editors=1100

If you go this link https://clay.global/about/ and go down till the image slider that is what I am trying to implement here.

Comment: How about think different. Autoplay suck. Use owl.next and owl.prev functions with own timing on hover.

Comment: @EveryScreamer Not even reinitializing `owl.owlCarousel()` and changing `rtl` boolean back and forth every `mouseenter` ever changes the autoplay direction. It does suck.

Comment: @AbanaClara I have tried to change rtl direction on mouseover event but it does not happen.